# Xcode 8 Autolayout iPad and iPad PRO 12.9

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to understand if new autolayout, vary for traits and size classes can be set to distinguish between a iPad and iPad Pro 12.9

From what I can see the trait / size classes are the same for both.

So how to do create a storyboard that is optimised for the larger pro ?

Is it possible via autolayout or is this only achievable by code.

For example if I had a image and a button size could I make them have a different X & Y , width and height value for iPad and iPad Pro (12.9)

Thanks

Comment: As you said yourself - all iPads have regular/regular size class, so there is no way to distinguish between them using size classes.

Comment: You could use height/width constraints with multipliers to make your image and button proportional to the screen size.

Comment: @MikeTaverne how do you do that ?